# How do I set a files last modified date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, last-modified

I am writing multiple files via `fs.createWriteStream`.

I want to alter the `Last Modified` value to a specific time-stamp, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this, I need some directions to get it working.

I'm using this code, in a loop that has a `file` argument.

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/images/' + file.id + file.ext, { flags: 'w', encoding: null, mode: 0666 });

stream.on('finish', function(data) {
    fs.utimes(stream.path, file.ts, file.ts, function (err) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        console.log('>> Set mtime to: '+ file.ts);
    });
});

client.getBlob(file.id).then(function(blob) {
    blob.pipe(stream);
});
```

It's logging the correct things on the finish event, but in windows my modified dates are the time that the file was created.

Node version is `0.10.25`.

Answer (score 0):

Once stream has finished its operation and closed, perhaps a quick open and append of one character to the file will set a last modified date closer to what you want?

Comment: I want to set the date to the files original date that is stored in the file object, so it could be years ago, or 2 days ago - but almost never the at the time I write the file.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case I'm not sure how you would go about doing that in javascript.

Comment: Node can do this, but I can't get it to work. (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_utimes_path_atime_mtime_callback)

Comment: so you want `atime` (created date?) to be the same as `mtime' (modified date?)